# C# convert substring with no value to 0

Tags: c#

Using C#, I need to convert a substring to an int even if the value of the substring is null.

My code reads lines of a text file and then assigns certain parts of the text to strings.

```
int _CUSTBAL = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(5, 2));
```

Example Text:

12345 10 etc
12346 20 etc
12347        etc

The issue I'm having is that if the line contains a blank space it throws an exception.  I need it to return zero if the substring contain a blank.  For example.  If the text is formatted blank9 then I need to return 09.  I've tried using nullable types but that doesn't do the trick.  Thanks

Comment: String.Replace(" ", "0")  should work to remove blanks and place a zero there.

Comment: What do you mean by "return 09"? Convert.ToInt32() returns int. Do you mean you need string representation? not int?

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by 090, there is no such number. you can't have leading zeros in an integer.

Comment: there's too many unknowns.  In one of your examples you want 3 digits, which contradicts the rest of the question.  And you can't have leading zeros in an `int` type.  Figure out what you want.

Comment: Bobby search before asking so you don't get downvotes, believe me on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
string sub = line.Substring(5, 2).Trim();
int _CUSTBAL = sub != string.Empty ? Convert.ToInt32(sub) : 0;
```

It takes away all whitespaces and returns 0 for an empty string.

or else:

```
string sub = line.Substring(5, 2);
int _CUSTBAL = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sub) ? Convert.ToInt32(sub) : 0;
```

Comment: your second option is perfect.  Thanks

Comment: @BobbyTurkalino, one thing I'd point out about `ToInt32` vs `TryParse`, is if `sub` ends up being something other than a null reference or a number, e.g. ` E` or something, you will get a `FormatException` -- `TryParse` will give you a 0 for anything that isn't a number, whether it's a null reference, letters, etc.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15895040/3199927) post

Answer (score 3):

If `TryParse()` fails, `_CUSTBAL` will be 0.

```
int _CUSTBAL;
int.TryParse(line.Substring(5, 2), out _CUSTBAL);
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OU0akz) is a fiddle demonstrating your test cases.

And if you really do want leading zeros, `_CUSTBAL.ToString("000")` will turn, for example, 2 to 002 and 20 to 020.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that yourself.

```
string toConvert;

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    toConvert = "0";
else
    toConvert = line;

Convert.ToInt32(toConvert);
```

Comment: I think you need `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check for blank value?

```
var value = line.Substring(5, 2);
var _CUSTBAL = String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(value);
```